# Calling business objects (BO) page through Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, iframe, business-objects

I am trying to call an Business Objects page through AJAX call, to load that page into an HTML iFrame and keep it ready, even before the user navigates to that page. Since the BO page load will take sometime, it is required to go through AJAX call.
I tried through .load() or .get() methods, but they doesn't work due to cross domain. Is there any way to load the BO page into the iFrame, even before navigating to that page ? If anyone have tried before, please guide.
Thanks.

Comment: If you're using an iFrame, you don't need AJAX to start the request. Just set the src attribute of the iFrame.

Comment: Papa, even when i set the src attribute of the iFrame, i don't find the page to be loading immediately. Only, when the page containing that iFrame is navigated, the URL is called. I want to get the BO page to be loaded and ready, before navigating to that page. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some code? Is the iframe being loaded straight away when the page is loaded?

Comment: Papa, Yes, i see the iFrame is loaded only when the page is navigated. Below is the code.        var oHtmlContent = "<div id=\"diviframe\"><iframe id=\"iframe\" src=\"\" height=\"" +
          (window.innerHeight - 100) +
          "px\" width=\"100%\" ></iframe></div>"; $('#iframe').prop('src', "http//BO-URL");   The above type of code will load the BO URL only when the page is navigated and not before navigation. I am looking for some code, that can load before the user navigates to that page. Thanks.